# jQuery/AJAX read html inside div tag

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I'm getting HTML from a database via AJAX but when I output that HTML into a div, it only shows the actual HTML text, not the pictures and such as a browser sees it. Anyone know how to do this? I'm outputting the HTML in textarea #html and want to see it rendered in div #preview. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#creative').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/app/components/MailingsReport.cfc',
            //POST method is used
            type: "POST",
            //pass the data 
            data: {
                method: "getCreativeHTML",
                creativeID: $('#creative').val(),
                datasource: "shopping_cart"
                 },
            dataType: "html",
            //contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(response){
                var obj = $.trim(response);
                //alert("response");
                if (obj == '"0 records"') {
                    $('#preview').html("No creative found.");
                }
                else { 
                    $('#html').val( obj );
                    $('#preview').html( obj );
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: If you use Firefox try to inspect the changes using Web Console and the Page Inspector. Is the HTML really been placed into the `#preview` ?

Comment: Hey @RobertNiestroj - yes it's inside #preview but as the actual html (<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border...)

Comment: Hey @RobertNiestroj - I'm using ColdFusion to return the query and here's an example of the Response in firebug: <wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><string>&lt;img src="http://address.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/07/01.jpg" width="600" height="87" alt="our alt" border="0"&gt;</string></data></wddxPacket>

Comment: I found the answer... in the <cffunction> I need to specify returnformat="plain"

Answer (score 2):

I see you answered your own question.  You could also consider the jQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method, which is designed for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `$("myul").append("<li>anitem<\li>").` give that a shot an see if it works.